# Intercepting packets from Electron App to keyboard in Linux

Tags: javascript, usb, sniffing

I have a USB keyboard which has an Electron app to set the macros on the keyboard. I unpacked the `app.asar` file, and the JS files seem to indicate that it is a ReactJS app, and is a minified production build, and obfuscated too much to reverse engineer.

Another way to approach the problem seemed to be to use USB sniffer. I chose WireShark for the job. I wanted to capture all the data packets sent from the app to the keyboard, and hoped to reverse engineer that. The problem is, I can't find a way to capture the raw USB stream. I tried using WireShark to monitor `usbmon0`, but there is too much metadata, and separating the raw data from the protocol metadata seems to be a daunting task.

I do not have a hardware USB sniffer or a JTAG debugger. Is there a simple way to capture all the raw data going from the app to the keyboard?

Comment: Wireshark has built-in filter. Why don't you use him? Check which method it uses to send/read data and apply correct filter like `usb.transfer_type == 0x01`

Comment: @morsisko unfortunately, all the transfer type is  0x01. However, this is an example of a packet:

    `0000   c0 75 90 00 22 91 ff ff 53 01 84 06 03 00 2d 3c`

    `0010   4b 71 d1 5e 00 00 00 00 7c 67 0d 00 8d ff ff ff`
    `0020   40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`
    `0030   08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 02 00 00 00 00 00 00`

Unfortunately, I can't make heads or tails of this packet.

Comment: Was there a driver installed?

Comment: @multithr3at3d no driver. Like I said, this is a keyboard on Linux. There was no driver installed.